# how to disable input file property with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the input file property with Javascript so that it couldn't browse the file.
Please help.

Found this but it is in Jquery

```
$('#images').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Like any type of input or button, a file input has a `disabled` property that you can simply assign to `true` or `false` with an `=` operator.

Answer (score -1):

Access the HTML disabled attribute then set it to true, you can try with

```
document.getElementById("images").disabled = true;
```

For more information,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled

Comment: I have different question can I ask here please?

Comment: @cenica no please ask a new question instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).